# Every derived table must have its own alias Error?

Tags: mysql, perl

---

Why my following sub routine throws an every derived table must have its own alias error?

```
sub ok_wait
{
my $str= shift;
$DBH = &connect or die "Cannot connect to the sql server \n";
$DBH->do("USE $str;");
my $stmt="select name,jobs_ok,jobs_wait from (select name,jobs_ok,jobs_wait from files order by name limit 5) t union all select 'others',sum(jobs_wait)as jobs_wait,sum(jobs_ok)as jobs_ok from(select jobs_wait,jobs_ok from files order by name limit -1 offset 5) t;";
my $sth = $DBH->prepare( $stmt );
$sth->execute() or die $sth->errstr;
my $tmp = 0;
while(my @row_array=$sth->fetchrow_array)
{
if ($tmp == 0) {
$var_ok .= "\[\"$row_array[0] \($row_array[2]\)\",$row_array[2]\]";
$var_wait .= "\[\"$row_array[0] \($row_array[1]\)\",$row_array[1]\]";
$tmp++;
}
$sth->finish;
$DBH->disconnect();
}
```

Comment: maybe because you've got derived tables with no alias?

Comment: the above changes shows syntax error@billynoah

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from (select jobs_wait,jobs_ok from files order by name limit -1 ' @billynoah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the limit value

```
"select name,jobs_ok,jobs_wait from ((select name,jobs_ok,jobs_wait from files order by name limit 5) union all (select 'others',sum(jobs_wait)as jobs_wait,sum(jobs_ok) as jobs_ok from (select jobs_wait,jobs_ok from files order by name limit 0 offset 5) foo)) foo ";
```

Note: Not tested I just typed it here directly, but basically you need to put an alias to your sub queries.

Comment: Sorry, I'll leave it to GurV, but the syntax error could be lack of parenthesis.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from (select jobs_wait,jobs_ok from files order by name limit -1 ' @Learning

Comment: I had tested with your coded line exactly.Here every paranthesis are closed in right mannee@Learning

Comment: If you change the -1 to 1? Why do you need -1 for the limit? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: By using mysql query i tried to take the max of five rows and the remaining rows to be added and stored with new row name called 'others'@Learning

Comment: Is it possible to add type of the row name to the 'others' row@Learning

Comment: If you need to show the next 5 then limit has to be 5 as well Limit 5 Offset 5 this will skip 5 records.(I could be wrong thou.)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by add type of the row name? Can you elaborate on this one?

Comment: yes but here the others shows the values as null.How to change the text type along with row name @Learning

Comment: I still cannot understand what you mean by change the text type along with row name. Can you site an example?

Comment: Here we had added the new row name called 'others'.The thing is it prints as follows ` others        |         NULL |         NULL `.Why it is not printing the sum of the values.Instead it prints as NULL@Learning

Comment: That only means that there's a mistake in your query. If the query do not return a expected result most likely there is something wrong with your sql query. I would suggest to give an example data of your files table and the desired output based on the example data that you are going to provide. It will be easier this way instead of making a lengthy discussion.

Comment: Additionally, since its a different concern you should start a separate thread for that.